# Laravel Apache and Docker Permission Denied

Tags: laravel, docker, permission-denied

Hy guys,

i'm getting this error

[image: Permission Denied]

I don't understand, i check the path in Apache and docker-compose. 
I check the correct installation about laravel typing php artisan

[image: and it's ok] 
I open my phpinfo (blog/info.php) file and my test2.php (blog/public/test2.php) file correctly 
I tried to set the permission 777 to all file and directory inside my docker container but nothing. 
[image: Directory tree] 
i would like to see the correct base page of laravel installation and start to study this framework.

this is my Apache config file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foxsimracing
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    ServerAdmin email@example.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride all

        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>

        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils zip unzip
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli bcmath

# Installing xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Installing composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

RUN useradd -o -u 1000 -g www-data -m -s /bin/bash www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get autoremove -y
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

and this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
foxsimracing_app:
    build:
        context: ./foxsimracing_app
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: foxsimracing_app
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - ./foxsimracing_app/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        - ./foxsimracing_app/custom.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/custom.conf
        - ../../repo/foxsimracinghardware/blog:/var/www/html
    networks:
        - laravel
    depends_on:
        - mysql

mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: foxsimracing_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    volumes:
        - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: foxsimracing
        MYSQL_USER: simracing
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: simracing
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
        - laravel

phpmyadmin:
    container_name: foxsimracing_phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - "8088:80"
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    networks:
        - laravel

networks:
laravel:
```

my .env file in laravel app

```
APP_NAME=foxsimracing
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:/JPnIdjIdzyxw4N85h2Bl13K3m9qHoO//SPoMxqBfq4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found out the problem was in the apache configuration. 
 
I put it in /etc/apache2/sites-available and this is wrong because i had to put it into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. 
I moved in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and it's work!
I hope this is helpful for others people.